# Is wake lock commutative?

Tags: android, wakelock, android-wake-lock

Let's say an Android application acquires a wake-lock, and then launches another application by sending it an explicit intent. Does the effect of acquisition of wake-lock last while the other application is in the foreground ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [Keeping the Device Awake](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html) it's perfectly natural for a background application to grab and hold a CPU wakelock:

> One legitimate case for using a wake lock might be a background service that needs to grab a wake lock to keep the CPU running to do work while the screen is off. **Again, though, this practice should be minimized because of its impact on battery life.**

This action is pretty common. For example, imagine a music playing application. Even though the screen is off, or some other activity is in the foreground, it's fine for a background application to hold a wake lock to keep playing music.

Although that last line should really take a warning. As described in [Wakelocks and Battery Drain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=reMau7d0yeg&index=43&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE) those things tend to burn through battery pretty fast; and worse yet, is that it's a pretty common problem to not release them properly, and end up putting the device into a sleepless mode, where it never goes to sleep.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If an application that acquired a wake-lock were to cause another application to be started, by sending it an explicit intent, does the effect of holding the wake-lock extend to the new application as well ? I guess so.

Comment: Wakelocks are absolute. App A holds a wakelock; even though app B may be in the foreground, A can still keep the CPU awake.

Comment: Ah, thanks. That answers my question completely and thus accepting the answer.